# msck repair table query not working

Tags: hive, hiveql, partition, amazon-athena

I have stored partitioned data in s3 in hive format like this.

```
/bucket/year=2017/month=02/date=20
/bucket/year=2017/month=02/date=21
```

I have created an external table in Athena

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mts_prod_8(
event struct<type:string, id:string>,
longitude double,
application string,
latitude double,
device_id string,
trip_id string
)

PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, date string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.format' = '1') LOCATION 's3://mts-data/dispatcher/'
```

Every day new partition is getting added in s3 and for loading the same into athena table i run following query

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE TABLE_NAME
```

But somehow above query getting failed and metadata is not getting loaded.

I am completely stuck in it.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "getting failed"?

Comment: After taking too much time it is not giving successful results, query state is not changing from running->successful. Query execution is not getting completed.